# JavaScript carousel not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

So im trying to make a carousel full screen for a presentation. Im not a pro coder im in a phase of learning. I have this code and im having as you can see and error and the carousel is all broken and i dont know why. I could appreciate some guidance or help.

```js
var $item = $('.carousel .item');
var $wHeight = $(window).height();

$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

var $numberofSlides = $('.item').length;
var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

$('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
  var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
  if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
  }
});

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #B9121B;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="sliderjava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderstyle.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicadores -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=397" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>First Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=689" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Second Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=675" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Third Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=658" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=638" data-color="tomato" alt="Fifth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controlos -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _I also don't know what you're doing_

Comment: Try coming up with a more expressive title, please.

Comment: Your title is so catchy that everyone will look to flag this question. Please try editing and restructure it with relevant details only.

Comment: it seems you forgot to include jquery before the carouse script?

Answer (score 1):

Please add jquery reference and it should be before the carouse script in your page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstraps's carousel but you have not attached anything necessary to make it work unfortunately. Please make the following things to make your carousel work.

1. Attach Bootstrap's css.
2. Attach `jQuery` library.
3. Attach Bootstrap's javascript.

```js
var $item = $('.carousel .item');
    var $wHeight = $(window).height();

    $item.height($wHeight); 
    $item.addClass('full-screen');

    var $numberofSlides = $('.item').length;
    var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

    $('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
      var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
      if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $('.carousel img').each(function() {
      var $src = $(this).attr('src');
      var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
      $(this).parent().css({
        'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
        'background-color' : $color
      });
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function (){
      $wHeight = $(window).height();
      $item.height($wHeight);
    });

    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000,
      pause: "false"
    });
```

```css
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #B9121B;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="sliderjava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderstyle.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicadores -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=397" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=689" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=675" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=658" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=638" data-color="tomato" alt="Fifth Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controlos -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```